# Preventing Child from firing parent's click event doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

The idea that the user writes a todo, and I will be displayed in a div, if you click at the div the writing will be strikes through, but if you hover will be a small div with a trash icon displayed. My problem is that every time I click on the child element the written part of the parent div will be striked through. How can I prevent the child from acting the same as the parent? I write event.stopPropagation(); but doesn't work.

```
let text_field = document.getElementById("fname");
let count = 0;
text_field.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if(event.key === "Enter") {
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    event.preventDefault();
    let block_to_insert = document.createElement('div');
    block_to_insert.id = "div-created"+count+"";
    let text_to_insert = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    let text=block_to_insert.innerHTML = ''+text_field.value;
    block_to_insert.classList.add('todo-div-todo');
 
    let where_to_insert = document.getElementById('outer-div');
    where_to_insert.appendChild( block_to_insert );
    


    block_to_insert.onclick = function(e){
      block_to_insert.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
    }
    
      block_to_insert.onmouseover = function(){
      let delete_div = document.createElement('div');
      let text=delete_div.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash" style="color:white"></i>';
      delete_div.classList.add('delete-todo');
      delete_div.id = "delete-div"+count+"";

      let place_to_insert = document.getElementById(block_to_insert.id);
      place_to_insert.appendChild( delete_div );
      document.getElementById("delete-div"+count+"").addEventListener('click',function (event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
     },true);
    }

    
  }
});
```

[image: If I click at the red trash icon,the text will be striked thorugh]

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @chovy same issue...

Comment: use css instead of js

Comment: @chovy I don't think I can because there are two events, one in parent and one in child div. If I make pointer-events:none ,I will prevent the child event that I want

Comment: Just to be clear, whats happening is that when you click on one todo-list-item, all of them gets striked through?

Comment: @ParadigmShift,no not all of them but only the div I clicked,I will now upload a photo and you can see